# SPARQL Distance problem WIKIDATA - problem with distance measuring

Tags: sparql, owl, wikidata

I am doing SPARQL exercise right now - I want to find all places that dont have airport in 100km range.
Right now I am stuck, cause I wanted to union them to filter data, but that isnt working.
Please help me to understand how to connect data to be able to filter the distance :)
To simplify code I changed all the cities to only Berlin.

```
SELECT ?placeCoor WHERE{

  {
        SELECT ?placeCoor WHERE{
    ?place wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1248784.
    ?place wdt:P625 ?placeCoor.
    }
  }
    UNION
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?berlinLoc WHERE {
     wd:Q64 wdt:P625 ?berlinLoc . 

SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }                                                                }
   }
  FILTER (geof:distance(?placeCoor, ?berlinLoc) >5 )
}
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen when calling `geof:distance`? GeoSPARQL isn't supported by all triple stores, especially not by Blazegraph which is the backend of public Wikidata. They have their own implementation which you can use: https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/GeoSpatial

Comment: I wanted to filter city with railway station. geof:distance should describe the distance between two geo points. Could you tell me how to query points out of the circle? I can not find any example which would negate being in a circle

Comment: your current query is looking for airports **not** railway stations ... and I don't get it, do you want cities with no airport nearby or with airport nearby? And indeed you can use the `geof:distance` function, but it would rather inefficient - I mean, what do you want to compare? Each city with each airport, right?

Comment: like that query returns you all airports not being in 5km radius: `SELECT ?place ?placeCoor WHERE {
  wd:Q64 wdt:P625 ?berlinLoc.
  ?place (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q1248784;
    wdt:P625 ?placeCoor.
  FILTER((geof:distance(?placeCoor, ?berlinLoc)) > 5 )
}`